# Vue3 gets the components of keep-alive cache

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I use vuejs3+typescript to build a background management system, and use keep-alive to cache pages. How can I get the currently cached components?

Answer (score 1):

The `<keep-alive>` component [exposes its cache *only in dev builds* as `__v_cache`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/d045055/packages/runtime-core/src/components/KeepAlive.ts#L102). You can use a [template ref](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html) on the `<keep-alive>`, and read the `__v_cache` from its internal instance (`$`):

```html
<template>
  <button @click="logKeepAliveCache">Log keep-alive cache</button>

  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <keep-alive ref="keepAlive">
      <component :is="Component" />
    </keep-alive>
  </router-view>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const keepAlive = ref()

const logKeepAliveCache = () => {
  // The cache is a `Map`, where the entry keys are
  // metadata about the component's file, and the
  // filename is stored in `__file`.
  console.log([...keepAlive.value.$?.__v_cache.keys()].map((x) => x.__file))
}
</script>
```

Note the `__v_cache` is not available in production builds.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-access-keep-alive-cache?file=src/App.vue)